# How to use superscript in XML for android, without using java

Tags: xml, android-layout, superscript

How do I add superscript to a TextView in XML for android in the xml document itself? Every answer I've seen requires you to set it in java. I've tried using the html tags in both the strings.xml and the layout I'm working on itself, and all that happens is I get an error about not using a < or it prints out the tags as well